# Does Google detect files in the Wordpress plugin directory

Tags: plugins, seo

Will Google detect files in the Wordpress plugin directory?

Example:

```
/wp-content/plugins/random-image-gallery-with-fancy-zoom/js/

/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/videojs/demo.html
```

I put blank index.php's on the folder and directory, and a meta noindex in the HTML. Will this keep Google from indexing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will, but why not go further and add a [robots.txt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress#Robots.txt_Optimization)?

```
# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*

# Google AdSense
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

# digg mirror
User-agent: duggmirror
Disallow: /

# global
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-content/cache/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /comments/
Disallow: /category/*/*
Disallow: */trackback/
Disallow: */feed/
Disallow: */comments/
Disallow: /*?
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
```